# How to Add Wrapper to Infinite Scroll Javascript?

Tags: posts, archive-template, infinite-scroll

I'm using Wordpress and manually adding Infinte Scroll from paulirish on GitHub: https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/

It loads properly, but how can I add a wrapper around all my posts?

Essentially, I'm outputting each post within a `<li>` tag. And I want to add an `<ol>` to surround/wrap the list item of posts. Any thoughts how to do so?

For Reference, this is the script I'm using in the functions.php file:

```
    /**
 * Load Javascript for Infinte Scroll
 */
function custom_theme_js(){
    wp_register_script( 'infinite_scroll',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js', array('jquery'),null,true );
    if( ! is_page_template( 'archive' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('infinite_scroll');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_theme_js');


/**
 * Infinite Scroll
 */
function custom_infinite_scroll_js() {
    if( ! is_page_template( 'archive' ) ) { ?>
    <script>
    var infinite_scroll = {
        loading: {
            img: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif",
            msgText: "<?php _e( 'Loading the next set of posts...', 'custom' ); ?>",
            finishedMsg: "<?php _e( 'All posts loaded.', 'custom' ); ?>"
        },
        "nextSelector":".navigation .nav-next a",
        "navSelector":".navigation",
        "itemSelector":".archive-image",
        "contentSelector":"#archive-content"
    };
    jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll );
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_infinite_scroll_js',100 );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would control the markup by editing archive.php. Here you can add a wrapper to individual posts.